# Array range for swift

Tags: arrays, swift

What could be the swift equivalent of following python code ?

```
array =[ "a", "b", "c"]
print(array[1:])
```

( Above statement prints every element from first index upto end of array.
 **Output** ['b', 'c'])

**Edit**
Is there a way where this could be done with out using array.count ? Since the array.count is redundant if I say  want every element from second position

Comment: You could iterate over the array 'for string in array' this wouldn't use 'array.count' but what is against using it?

Comment: If expecting to drop only the first element, `dropFirst(array)` is usable.

Comment: @milo526 : I was expecting a more readable solution. Logically it should take only 1 argument in consideration(like python does). So I was wondering if there is some thing similar in swift. Considering the enhancements in swift 1.2, I think they might introduce this feature in future.

Comment: There's a library up on GitHub that lets you subscript an Array with a single argument using a `..` operator, so `array[1..]` will give you all members of the array from the 1st index on up. It's not updated for Swift 1.2, but may work as is.... https://github.com/letvargo/LazyListSequence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Swift 4, there is many ways to solve your problem. According to your needs, you may choose one of the **six following patterns**.

---

#### #1. Using `Array` [`dropFirst()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688121-dropfirst) method

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]
let arraySlice = array.dropFirst()
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints ["b", "c"]
```

---

#### #2. Using `Array` [`suffix(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1689680-suffix) method

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]
let arraySlice = array.suffix(from: 1)
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints ["b", "c"]
```

---

#### #3. Using `Array` [`suffix(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1687909-suffix) method

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]
let arraySlice = array.suffix(array.endIndex.advanced(by: -1))
// let arraySlice = array.suffix(array.count - 1) // also works
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints ["b", "c"]
```

---

#### #4. Using `Array` [`subscript(_:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1540825-subscript) and `CountableRange`

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]
let range = array.startIndex.advanced(by: 1) ..< array.endIndex
// let range = 1 ..< array.count // also works
let arraySlice = array[range]
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints ["b", "c"]
```

---

#### #5. Using `Array` [`subscript(_:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1540825-subscript) and `CountableClosedRange`

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]
let range = 1 ... array.count - 1 // also works
let arraySlice = array[range]
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints ["b", "c"]
```

---

#### #6. Using `Array` [`subscript(_:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1540825-subscript) and `CountablePartialRangeFrom`

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]
let range = 1...
let arraySlice = array[range]
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints ["b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get sub range of an swift array like that:

```
let array =[ "a", "b", "c"]
//be sure that your array.count has more than 1 item (in this case)
let subArray1 = array[1..<array.count]
print(subArray1)
//or
let subArray2 = array[1...array.count-1]
print(subArray2)
```

This is 2 notes from Swift Programming Language book

> “Use .. to make a range that omits its upper value, and use ... to
>   make a range that includes both values.”

And

> “If you try to use subscript syntax to retrieve or set a value for an
>   index that is outside of an array’s existing bounds, you will trigger
>   a runtime error. However, you can check that an index is valid before
>   using it, by comparing it to the array’s count property. Except when
>   count is 0 (meaning the array is empty), the largest valid index in an
>   array will always be count - 1, because arrays are indexed from zero.”

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you're looking for in the following way:

**1.** Create a custom struct to store a start and end index. If `startIndex` or `endIndex` is `nil` this will be taken to mean the range extends infinitely in that direction.

```
struct UnboundedRange<Index> {
    var startIndex, endIndex: Index?

    // Providing these initialisers prevents both `startIndex` and `endIndex` being `nil`.
    init(start: Index) {
        self.startIndex = start
    }

    init(end: Index) {
        self.endIndex = end
    }
}
```

**2.** Define operators to create an `BoundedRange` as having to use the initialisers will lead to some quite unsightly code, in my option.

```
postfix operator ... {}
prefix  operator ... {}

postfix func ... <Index> (startIndex: Index) -> UnboundedRange<Index> {
    return UnboundedRange(start: startIndex)
}

prefix func ... <Index> (endIndex: Index) -> UnboundedRange<Index> {
    return UnboundedRange(end: endIndex)
}
```

Some example usage:

```
1...  // An UnboundedRange<Int> that extends from 1 to infinity.
...10 // An UnboundedRange<Int> that extends from minus infinity to 10.
```

**3.** Extend the `CollectionType` so it can handle `UnboundedRange`s.

```
extension CollectionType {
    subscript(subrange: UnboundedRange<Index>) -> SubSequence {
        let start = subrange.startIndex ?? self.startIndex
        let end = subrange.endIndex?.advancedBy(1) ?? self.endIndex
        return self[start..<end]
    }
}
```

**4.** To use this in your given example:

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]

array[1...] // Returns ["b", "c"]
array[...1] // Returns ["a", "b"]
```