# Cannot cast CountablePartialRangeFrom<Int> to Range<Int>

Tags: swift

I have a parameter for a method that is of type `Range<Int>?` that defaults to nil. I'd like a nice succinct way of saying "Use the given range or use the whole range". Nothing I've done seems to quite work, I feel like this *should* though...

```
class func fileNames(entries: Array<DBFILESMetadata>, range: Range<Int>? = nil) -> Array<String> {
    return entries[range ?? 0... as Range<Int>].map{ $0.name }.filter{ $0.hasSuffix(".jpg") }
}
```

...I get the error `Cannot convert value of type 'CountablePartialRangeFrom<Int>' to type 'Range<Int>' in coercion`, which I totally get, but then why does this work (via pattern #6 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42860580/84783)

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]
let range = 1...
let arraySlice = array[range]
```

I can just do this in a conditional, but feel like a one liner should work.

Comment: A `CountablePartialRangeFrom` is not a `Range`, it's a `PartialRange`

Comment: @Alexander `cast` is the wrong word, I should have said `coerced`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change your method parameter to `CountableRange` and pass the array indices property in case of nil:

```
class func fileNames(entries: Array<DBFILESMetadata>, range: CountableRange<Int>? = nil) -> Array<String> {
    return entries[range ?? entries.indices].map{ $0.name }.filter{ $0.hasSuffix(".jpg") }
}
```

Comment: I don't know that i am right or not but `CountableClosedRange` should be there at   `CountableRange` because `CountableRange` will not contain upperbounds like 0..<8 value in range would be 0 - 7

Comment: Thats how it is. You could also use `CountableClosedRange` but you would need to pass a  `CountableClosedRange` also after the nil coalescing operator

Comment: This does work actually and works for what I want. Any idea why something like `["a", "b", "c"][1...]` works though?

Comment: You said that you needed the whole range in case of nil. What is the parameter type you would like to use in your method? You need to provide a method for each if you would like to be able to use more than one type. This might help you to understand what I mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language/38215613?s=1|43.6266#38215613

Comment: No I mean based on the docs Array `subscript` wants an `Int` or a `Range<Int>`, but passing it `CountablePartialRangeFrom<Int>` is fine. There's some jump I'm missing as to why that's ok. Know what I mean?

Comment: If you would like to use `CountableClosedRange` you need to provide a default of the same type such as  `range ?? entries.startIndex...(entries.index(entries.endIndex, offsetBy: -1, limitedBy: entries.startIndex) ?? entries.startIndex)`

Comment: @LeoDabus, I think you're responding to something Prashant said above.

Comment: No I am saying that you need to implement all the methods if you would like to be able to call that method with `CountableRange` , `CountableClosedRange`, `PartialRangeUpTo`, `PartialRangeThrough` and `PartialRangeFrom`. When using the nil coalescing operator the default value needs to match the value type that precedes the `??` operator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163609/discussion-between-rob5408-and-leo-dabus).